# Knockout: Rules for custom binding triggers firing update method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can someone tell me why this works?

```
<div id="test">
    <label data-bind="dateText: TheDate"></label>
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.dateText = {
        update:         
                function(el, f_valueaccessor, allbindings, viewmodel, bindingcontext) 
        {
            // Get current value of supplied value
            var val = ko.unwrap(f_valueaccessor());

                        console.log('dt is ' + (typeof(val.dt) == 'function' ? '' : 'NOT ') + 'observable');

                        var dt = ko.unwrap(val.dt);

                        $(el).html(dt ? moment(dt).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '');
                }
};

function Model(data, mapping)
{
        var _this = this;

        if(data)
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, _this);

        this.TheDate = this.TheDate || { dt: ko.observable() }
}

var model = new Model({ TheDate: { dt: null } });

ko.applyBindings(model);

model.TheDate.dt('2001-01-01T01:01:01');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qkLzc5u5/2

The reason I ask is that I am having problems making this custom binding work in a real application - there, it displays any initial date fine but updates are not reflected in the text - however the `IsDated` computed does update, so the label is displayed; just blank.

I thought that the problem was that the binding is attached to `TheDate`, which is not an observable itself; only `dt` is.

However, the code above will in fact fire the update, so the date `01/01/2001` is shown, whereas I was expecting nothing to be displayed due to the null initial value.

Now this is actually exactly the behaviour I want, so I don't have a problem with this code - I am hoping to get a bit more of an insight into how the custom bindings know when to fire so I can debug my real world code better.

(Note that the object model for passing dates is fixed by a web service that I cannot change)

Comment: If in your other application the `dateText.update` method is not called, it could be that the bound field is not an observable, or the `update` function doesn't actually *read* the observable (which creates a dependency).

Comment: I have actually solved my problem now, and was an error so embarrassing I'm not going to share it. Could you expand on how reading the observable creates the dependency? Would that be happening in the ko.unwrap(val.dt) line? So KO runs all the bindings and makes a note of when any observable was called from one to add to a dependency 'table' or something? If you could give be a bit more detail as an answer I will be happy to mark it as the answer; I still don't feel I have any kind of grasp on how KO creates dependencies and I don't like magic :)

Comment: See http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/05/knockout-dependency-detection.html

Comment: And from the official doc :http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html

Comment: That knockmeout link is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.